# A legenda de um chart Primefaces não aparece quando faço o download da imagem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Quando o gráfico é carregado, a legenda carrega junto, mas quando faço o download da imagem a legenda não aparece..

Botão para fazer o download:

```
<p:commandLink onclick="return downloadImage();" 
    style="margin: 2%;">
    <h:graphicImage url="/RESOURCES/icons/grafico/download.png"
        styleClass="ui-image-icon-excel" style=" margin-top: 5%;" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Javascript do botão do download:

```
[![<script type="application/javascript">
               function downloadImage(){
               var image = PF('chart').exportAsImage();
               var imageSrc = $(image).attr('src');
               var url = imageSrc.replace(/^data:image\/\[^;\]+/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
               var link = document.createElement('a');
               link.download = "chart.png";
               link.href = url;
               document.body.appendChild(link);
               link.click();
               document.body.removeChild(link);
               return false;
            }
            </script>][1]][1]
```

Imagem do download (a legenda está em branco): 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Basta colocar no css do panelGrid que envolve o gráfico: `text-align: left;`